# Partially Connected with Multiple Datastores - C#/WPF Solution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm building a WPF, C#, .NET solution that needs to rapidly change data connections.
All the connections will eventually sync back to a parent Oracle database, but in the meantime, I might be pulling data from an access database, or a local sql server compact database, or an xml file, or even a web service, or sharepoint. Problem is, I might even need to add providers, and need to be able to keep the providers in sync with each other, and do it real time, with no loss of connection/seamless to the users. This is all dependent on what type of machine, which domain, and what kind of network connectivity we have, and is a client requirement, not something I can change.

Does anyone have a good recommendation for what the best way to accomplish this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the client explained why they need this functionality? Often they ask for things to solve a problem that they forsee, without adequate knowledge of how best to solve it.

If you're coding something like an application for a travelling salesman to use, which will have intermittent connectivity to the Oracle database, then maybe you should look at using some means other than a direct database connection for synchronising the databases.

Say using a WCF/SOAP service to pass serialized data objects back and forth or you could look at using MSMQ to transfer changes back and forth between the intermittently connected mobile application and the Oracle database server. It would, of course mean that you'll need to run a server side application/service to handle this data and pass it into the Oracle database, but it would allow for intermittent connections to be handled more easily without having to handle database connection error logic.

In the meantime if your client code should look at layering the code to use a factory Repository type pattern. As business logic just calls an interface it is then possible to use database specific code within your data layer that was decided upon at run time (say through a config setting).

Comment: Yes, the client actually has a lot of related/common data on several machines, some are using an access database, some are using sql server compact edition. Their web service is currently using XML, and they want to bring it all together, in one database, hence the Oracle database. However, they don't want to force any of their existing users to do something new, in a new application. They mainly want the data in one spot, so they can manager it one area, and get a set of metrics covering all of them, instead of doing it by hand like they are currently.

Comment: So you're looking at automating the housekeeping function initally?

Comment: Essentially, right now, it's all done by hand, they merge all the datasets together, in excel, one person spends 2 weeks doing it, and then spends another week building reports off of it, and then starts the process over again next month. They can't get weekly reporting, because it simply takes her too long to do it all. So my task, is to build a solution, that takes all these disconnected datasets and automatically sync/merge them with an Oracle backend, with an automated reporting solution off the Oracle backend, to provide monthly, and weekly metrics.

Answer (score 1):

you can create one or two tables in any of your server whcih will include all connection strings and the condtions on which data you need to use which connection .

and your business layer will be independent of connections .

other options is to use sofware facotry pattern.
there you can repository independent of connections and on run time decided which data repository will connect to whcih DB.

Comment: This still leaves the question of how to sync all those datastores unanswered.